# Using Storm Spout Tuples for triggering execution of further computations at certain times

Tags: stream, apache-storm

I want to connect some Storm Bolts to a TriggerSpout, which emits Tuples let's say every 3 - 4 hours or at certain times of the day. When the connected Bolts recieve a tuple from this TriggerSpout, further computation on aggregated data (which comes from another kafka spout) should be initiated. (In this case feature extraction for feeding a subsequent MLBolt)

Now, can I somehow make a Spout with its nextTuple() method expose this behavior?
Is this the way to go or can anyone suggest a better approach to do that? It's kind of a global clock for the cluster.

regards'n'thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a TriggerSpout, you could add ticks into your bolt. Add the following to your bolt implementation:

```
import backtype.storm.Constants;

@Override
public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS, 15);
    return conf;
}

public static boolean isTickTuple(Tuple tuple) {
    String sourceComponent = tuple.getSourceComponent();
    String sourceStreamId = tuple.getSourceStreamId();
    return sourceComponent.equals(Constants.SYSTEM_COMPONENT_ID)
            && sourceStreamId.equals(Constants.SYSTEM_TICK_STREAM_ID);
}
```

In your execute() method, you first check whether the input is a tick tuple, then proceed with your logic.

Comment: thanks, by the time this answer reached me I already implemented the TriggerSpout as intended. Going for this approach provides the possibility to set certain times of the day when action shall take place, whereas when using tick tuples you are bound to a fixed frequency only.

Comment: @t-h- how did you make TriggerSpout emit a tuple at a particular time of the day (same 5 pm daily)? Is this TriggerSpout publically available?